# how input image canvas to excel (JS)

Tags: javascript, excel

help with exporting convas image to excel file here is what i tried via bible jsPDF and via FileSaver:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("get_images")).then(function(canvas) {
var my_screen = canvas;
var dpf = new jsPDF();
saveAs(my_screen.toDataURL(), 'fdlfs.xlsx')
dpf.addImage(my_screen.toDataURL(), 'JPEG', 0, 0)
dpf.save("dowld.xlsx")

  });
}
```

Comment: You want to export an image as... excel file? Why on earth? And why are you using jsPDF to try to accomplish that?

Comment: I need to take a screenshot of a table and send it to excel on click.
jsPDF I used because I saw this option on other forums

Comment: You're using html2canvas, which means you're starting from an HTML table, correct? So why would you convert that to a canvas in the first place when you can just read the table data off the cells? Makes no sense at all. And jsPDF is to create *PDFs*.

Comment: I already read the data from the table, but I need to implement the screenshot function, where the screenshot is transferred to excel

Comment: What does that even mean? "transfer a screenshot to excel"? A screenshot is a bunch of pixels, how is that supposed to end up as excel table? And again, why convert a *table* into a bunch of pixels in the first place when your goal is an xls doc? Makes zero sense. It's literally like printing a table and scanning it back in to make a copy of it. Nonsense.

Comment: I don’t see the point in this, but the employer wants it that way))

Comment: The employer says to transfer an HTML table to an excel document via screenshot...? Do they think that will keep the formatting and styling? Do they want to edit the table further or just download it somehow? Anyway, here's how to create a CSV file from a table: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/n5ztkm6w/